# Carriage Return Line Feed in MXML

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mxml

I have this line:

```
text="{selectedOrder.targetLocationName} 'crlf' {pickUpLocationHTML}"
```

Does anybody has an idea how to make this work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `\r\n`? `\n` is enough to make a newline in flash though (newlines are unix style; `\r\n` will actually give you the 2 newlines, like if you had `\r\n\r\n` in Windows).

So, perhaps you need something like (not tested!):

```
text="{selectedOrder.targetLocationName}\n{pickUpLocationHTML}"
```